# Display (in Template) choice from Model - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-template-filters

I need to call to choice field in Models from Template.
**models.py**:

```
...
CAT = (
    ("1", "1"),
    ("2", "2"),
)
cat = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPE, default="")
...
```

**views.py**:

```
def cat(request):
    my_model = Model.objects.all()
    return render(...{'post': post})
```

**template.html**:

```
{% for i in my_model%}
    {{ i.cat }} 
    # This shows DUPLICATES if I have couple posts with same cat. 
    # I want to display uniques in choices (I am not interested in posts at all)
{% endfor %}
```

So how can I call to choices in model from template, without showing duplicates?

> **P.S**: I gone through choices docs, nothing helped: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: in views: my_model = Model.objects.values('cat').distinct() and in template {% for i in my_model %} {{ i.cat }} {% endfor %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TommyL said:
**views.py**:

`my_model = Model.objects.values('cat').distinct()`

**template.html:**

```
{% for i in my_model %} 
    {{ i.cat }} 
{% endfor %}
```

*This solution works for me*

Answer (score 1):

If you just want choices there, You don't need to query database, just pass `CAT` choices in context.

```
def cat(request):
    my_model = Model.objects.all()
    return render(...{'post': post, 'cats': Model.CAT})
```

and in your template just loop over `cats`

```
{% for item in cats %}
    {{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use .distinct() on the query, e.g:

```
Model.objects.all().distinct()
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: In his case: Model.objects.values('cat').distinct()

Answer (score 0):

I thought you were asking for how to display the value in templates.
So if you want to get `cat` from your model, this should work the trick with `values_list()` and `distinct()`

```
def cat(request):
    my_model = Model.objects.values_list('field_name').distinct()
    return render(...{'my_model': my_model})
```

Comment: I would like to call to choices from templates to model, sorry for confusing sentence at the end of my question :(

Comment: can you just edit your question with real values of what you've tried and an example of the output expected

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.From model pass to template dropdownlist

models.py

```
Class MyCategory(models.Model):
 CAT_CHOICES=(
    ('1','1'),
    ('2','2'),
    )

  category=models.charField(max_length=2,choices=CAT_CHOICES)
```

views.py

```
def view_category(request):
     category_choices=MyCategory.CAT_CHOICES
     template_name='your_template.html'
     context={'category':category_choices}
     return render(request,template_name,context)
```

template

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>category</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <select name="category">
       {%for mykey,myvalue in category %}
            <option value="{{mykey}}">{{myvalue}}</option>
        {%endfor%}
     </select>

    </body>

</html>
```